# Swift NSPredicate throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1, address=0x1) when compounding statements

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to use NSPredicate in Swift to query Core Data but it throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1, address=0x1) error when trying to run it, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the file where the error happens

```
class LevelsScreenModel : UIViewController {

func getWord(level: Int, section: Int) -> String
{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Words")

    //This is the line where the error happens
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "level = %@", level)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "section = %@", section)

    let word = AppDelegate().managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [Words]

    if(word.count > 1)
    {
        for words in word
        {
            println(words.word)
            return words.word
        }
    }

    return "ERROR"
  }
}
```

Comment: The final error was due to not being able to do "AppDelegate()." to access the managedObjectContext. Instead this code worked for me "var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)" Hope this helps anyone

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The `%@` placeholder in predicate format strings is for Objective-C
objects, so you have to wrap the integer into an `NSNumber`:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "level = %@", NSNumber(integer: level))
```

or use `ld` instead to format a (long) integer:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "level = %ld", level)
```

Note also that

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: ...)
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: ...)
```

does *not* create a compound predicate, the seconds assignment simply
overwrites the first. You can use an `NSCompoundPredicate`:

```
let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "level = %ld", level)!
let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "section = %ld", section)!
fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate.andPredicateWithSubpredicates([p1, p2])
```

or simply combine the predicates with "AND":

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "level = %ld AND section = %ld", level, section)
```

Answer (score -3):

Instead of fussing around with format conversions and `AND` subpredicates, you could use the [PredicatePal](https://github.com/pixelglow/PredicatePal) framework:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = *(Key("level") == level && Key("section") == section)
```

Note that you'll need to use `==` instead of `=` for equality comparison.

Comment: And here's the problem with relying on 3rd party code, PredicatePal hasn't been updated in over a year