# swift - NSPREDICATE fails

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I try to filter coredata if articleID exists, if not add it to coredata. But I am gettin EXC_BAD_ACCESS error form let predicate line...

```
var error: NSError?
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Article")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "articleID == %@", articleID!)

fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
let results = self.context!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [Article]

    if results.count > 0 {
       println("already in the list")
    }else{
       newArticle.articleID = articleID!
       newArticle.abstract = abstract!
       newArticle.authorName = authorName!

        var saveError: NSError?
        self.context!.save(&saveError)

        if let _error = saveError {
            println("\(_error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            println("Saved!")
        }
    }
```

Comment: probably because **articleID** is nil

Comment: How I am going to implement an if check for NSPREDICATE?

Comment: just check if articleID != nil, and if it not, is nil put everything inside the if statement below the let predicate... line

Comment: I have to tables in my Article core data. Articles and favArticles, I mark an article a favArticle. And if an article is already faved I dont want to add it to favArtiles. I think I am checking the wrong articleID, because it is always nil...

Comment: it is an integer. I used %ld instead of %@ and it worked. Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "articleID == %@", articleID!)
```

articleID is an integer. I used %ld instead of %@ and it worked...

[Swift NSPredicate throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1, address=0x1) when compounding statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620794/swift-nspredicate-throwing-exc-bad-accesscode-1-address-0x1-when-compounding)