# Core Data NSPredicate not working

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Please help me there is no any specific error, run time stop

[image: there is screenshot]

```
func fachDataById(entityName: String, colummName: String, value: Int) -> Bool {
    let appDeleget = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let manegeContext = appDeleget.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequist = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
    print("ok fetchRequist")
    fetchRequist.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", colummName, value)

    do{
        let results = try manegeContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequist)
        print(results)
        return true
    }
    catch{
        print("Error")
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Try insert some breakpoints and inspect your fields to see if they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Does colummName and value are expected values that you are using them in your coredata table?

Comment: Did you debug this? Did you check the variables value? Are they valid?

Comment: You cannot use %@ for Int values.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28622582/3985749).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is %@ format for value:Int , cast it to value as NSObject or AnyObject like following:

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", colummName, value as NSObject)
```