# NSLocalizedString with variables in Swift doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have to locate these strings inside the if, which performs a countdown using the secondsRimanenti variable.

```
if secondiRimanenti > 1{
   self.statoRicerca = "Cerco sismometri disponibili... \(secondiRimanenti) secondi"
}
else{
   self.statoRicerca = "Cerco sismometri disponibili... \(secondiRimanenti) secondo"
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.timerStart()
```

The value of secondiRimanenti (seconds remaining) starts from 5 seconds down to 0 seconds
This is the error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4)
```

I have tried these two ways:

```
let appSec = String(format: NSLocalizedString("Cerco sismometri disponibili... %@ secondi", comment: ""), secondiRimanenti)
```

and

```
let appSec = String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("Cerco sismometri disponibili... %@ secondi", comment: ""), secondiRimanenti)
```

How can I solve it?
Thanks!!

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint just before this snippet? What is the value of `secondiRimanenti`? Btw if you want to localize plurals the recommended way is by using [stringsdict](https://medium.com/@vitaliikuznetsov/plurals-localization-using-stringsdict-in-ios-a910aab8c28c)

Comment: The value of secondiRimanenti (seconds remaining) starts from 5 seconds down to 0 seconds

Comment: I understand that it's _supposed_ to hold a value between 0...5 but can you verify it actually _does_ via a breakpoint?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620794/swift-nspredicate-throwing-exc-bad-accesscode-1-address-0x1-when-compounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong format specifier.

`%@` is for objects, an `Int` (assuming that `secondiRimanenti` **is** `Int`) is `%ld`.

```
let appSec = String(format: NSLocalizedString("Cerco sismometri disponibili... %ld secondi", comment: ""), secondiRimanenti)
```